# Libgdx spine2d skeleton animation

Tags: java, libgdx, spine

This is my code:

game init:

```
    playerAtlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("spineboy.atlas"));
    json = new SkeletonJson(playerAtlas);

    playerSkeletonData = json.readSkeletonData(Gdx.files.internal("spineboy.json"));
    playerAnimationData = new AnimationStateData(playerSkeletonData);

    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    skeletonRenderer = new SkeletonRenderer();

    skeleton = new Skeleton(playerSkeletonData);
    animationState = new AnimationState(playerAnimationData);


    animationState.setAnimation(0, "walk", true); // trackIndex, name, loop
```

render:

```
        animationState.update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    animationState.apply(skeleton);

    batch.begin();
    skeletonRenderer.draw(batch, skeleton);
    batch.end();

    Gdx.app.log("rendering", "x" +skeleton.getX());
    Gdx.app.log("rendering", "y"+skeleton.getY());

    skeleton.setPosition(300, 300);
```

And for some reason, I can't get my animation to show up.

I got this code from here and copied it:
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/98890/implementing-spine-animations-in-libgdx

I cant figure out why the animation isn't rendering!!

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this Test Class :

```
public class SimpleTest1 extends ApplicationAdapter {

    OrthographicCamera camera;
    SpriteBatch batch;
    SkeletonRenderer renderer;
    SkeletonRendererDebug debugRenderer;

    TextureAtlas atlas;
    Skeleton skeleton;
    AnimationState state;

    public void create () {

        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        renderer = new SkeletonRenderer();
        renderer.setPremultipliedAlpha(true); // PMA results in correct blending without outlines.
        debugRenderer = new SkeletonRendererDebug();
        debugRenderer.setBoundingBoxes(false);
        debugRenderer.setRegionAttachments(false);

        atlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("spineboy/spineboy.atlas"));
        SkeletonJson json = new SkeletonJson(atlas); // This loads skeleton JSON data, which is stateless.
        json.setScale(0.6f); // Load the skeleton at 60% the size it was in Spine.
        SkeletonData skeletonData = json.readSkeletonData(Gdx.files.internal("spineboy/spineboy.json"));

        skeleton = new Skeleton(skeletonData); // Skeleton holds skeleton state (bone positions, slot attachments, etc).
        skeleton.setPosition(250, 20);

        AnimationStateData stateData = new AnimationStateData(skeletonData); // Defines mixing (crossfading) between animations.
        stateData.setMix("run", "jump", 0.2f);
        stateData.setMix("jump", "run", 0.2f);

        state = new AnimationState(stateData); // Holds the animation state for a skeleton (current animation, time, etc).
        state.setTimeScale(0.5f); // Slow all animations down to 50% speed.

        // Queue animations on track 0.
        state.setAnimation(0, "run", true);
        state.addAnimation(0, "jump", false, 2); // Jump after 2 seconds.
        state.addAnimation(0, "run", true, 0); // Run after the jump.
    }

    public void render () {
        state.update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()); // Update the animation time.

        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        state.apply(skeleton); // Poses skeleton using current animations. This sets the bones' local SRT.
        skeleton.updateWorldTransform(); // Uses the bones' local SRT to compute their world SRT.

        // Configure the camera, SpriteBatch, and SkeletonRendererDebug.
        camera.update();
        batch.getProjectionMatrix().set(camera.combined);
        debugRenderer.getShapeRenderer().setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

        batch.begin();
        renderer.draw(batch, skeleton); // Draw the skeleton images.
        batch.end();

        debugRenderer.draw(skeleton); // Draw debug lines.
    }

    public void resize (int width, int height) {
        camera.setToOrtho(false); // Update camera with new size.
    }

    public void dispose () {
        atlas.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I think this is the second time you've answered one of my questions with a good answer! You're awesome!

Comment: I had the same problem the line that solve the problem for me is
"skeleton.updateWorldTransform();"

Answer (score 0):

I can't add comments, but there is a some additional info for Abhishek Aryan's post.

Now (oct, 22)you should use:

```
PolygonSpriteBatch batch;
..
batch = new PolygonSpriteBatch ();
```

to make his code work.